# cURL operation and PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have a frontend code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//make the request
$responseJSON = curl_exec($ch);
$response_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if ($response_status == 200) { // success
    // remove any "problematic" characters from the json string and then decode
    if (debug) {
        echo "----finish API of getAPI inside basic_function with status==200---";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "-------the json response is-------" ;  //.$responseJSON;
        var_dump($responseJSON);
        //print_r($responseJSON);
        echo "<br>";
    }
    return json_decode( preg_replace( '/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $responseJSON ) );
}
```

and I have a backend code which executed when cURL fired its operation with its URL. The backend code would therefore activated. So, I know cURL is operating.

```
$output=array (
  'status'=>'OK',
  'data'=>'12345'
)

$output=json_encode($output)

echo $output;
```

and `$output` shown on browser as `{"status":"OK","data":"12345"}`

However, I gone back to the frontend code and did `echo $responseJSON`, I got nothing. I thought the output of `{"status":"OK","data":"12345"}` would gone to the `$responseJSON`. any idea?

Here's output on Browser, something is very odd!  the response_status got 200 which is success even before the parsing of API by the backend code. I expect status =200 and json response after the {"status":"OK","data":"12345"}

=========================================================================================

inside the get API of the basic functions

```
-------url of cURL is -----http://localhost/test/api/session/login/?device_duid=website&UserName=joe&Password=1234&Submit=Submit



----finish API of getAPI inside basic_function with status==200---
-------the json response is-------string(1153) 


"************inside Backend API.php******************

---command of api is--/session/login/


---first element of api is--UserName=joe

--second element of api is---Password=1234

---third element of api is----Submit=Submit

----fourth element of api is---

-------inside session login of api-------------

{"status":"OK","data":"12345"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);` commented? 
See what happends if you comment that line.

Also try with the a basic code, if that works, smthing you added later is wrong:

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: can you post the Header response of your server, for that specific file, make sure it does not compress it or requires HTTP Auth!

Answer (score 0):

Try var_dump($responseJSON)

If it returns false try

> curl_error (  $ch )
>
> Returns a clear text error message for the last cURL operation.

Are you sure your $url is correct?

Comment: $url is correct, otherwise backend code wouldn't intercept it and process.    var_dump($responseJSON) returns string(1153). curl_error($ch) returns nothing.

Comment: With the new Information, i think you have somewhere in your API debug messages enabled, if you turn them off/delete it you should get you response